# cmd.exe - Windows 10 - typing numeric characters fails

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, keyboard, cmd.exe

I have an annoying problem with cmd.exe on Windows 10.
When I type something on the command line, all characters appear fine as typed. Except for the numeric characters of the main keyboard. Numeric characters of the NumPad also appear fine.
When I type a numeric character on the main keyboard, its 'shifted' character appears. Holding SHIFT key while typing doesn't do anything. Only when I hold LEFT ALT key while typing numeric characters, they appear as they should.
If I run cmd.exe with Administrator Rights, everything works fine! But I do not want to permanently set cmd.exe to start with Admin Rights, because then I always have to type in the password.
In every other program on my pc, I do not have this problem.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot: admin rights vs no admin rights]

Comment: Odd! Almost sounds like it's switched to French. The French AZERTY layout is the only one I know where you need to hold shift to get the numbers. The alt key throws that idea out the window, though.

Comment: This sounds like a manual change or a third-party program has defaulted the numerical keys to their secondary function first, versus the inverse. _(Since the alpha keys aren't auto-capitalized, and only the numeric keys are affected, it implies one of the `Shift` keys hasn't been defaulted to On.)_

Comment: @JW0914, OMG, you are right!
I use TypingAid  (the AutoHotkey autocompletion tool) to 'autocomplete' when I am typing. Disabling TypingAid immediately solved this problem! TypingAid uses the main keyboard numeric keys to let the user select which word to use for the autocompletion.
Now it sounds so obvious, but this thing has been driving me nuts for ages.
Thank you so much for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JW0914 for pointing me in the right direction of the solution!
I use TypingAid (the AutoHotkey autocompletion tool) to 'autocomplete' when I am typing.  TypingAid uses the main keyboard numeric keys to let the user select which word to use for the autocompletion. Disabling TypingAid immediately solved this problem!